# how do I upload file to sftp from google compute engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, sftp

To test I turned on remote login on my mac and tried ssh and sftp from my google cloud compute engine instance.  ssh user@ip and sftp@ip but in both cases the connection fails with "Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer." Is there a recommended way to upload files to sftp from google cloud?

Comment: Can you connect to your server from any other machine on Internet (outside your local network)?

Comment: yes I can  connect.

Comment: So show us as output of `ssh -vv user@ip` from both the GCE and the other machine + Is it newly setup GCE machine with all defaults? Or an existing machine, that might have special network rules that prevent outgoing connections?

Comment: Here is the debug output from ssh -vv user@ip. I can run the same command fine locally.


OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb, OpenSSL 1.0.2t 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xxx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: There are no special network rules - the machine was created with default settings.

Comment: Do not post important information in comments. Edit them into your question.